# Which version of Magento is used for extension devlopement

Tags: magento

I have planned to develop an extension in Magento e commerce domain.
which version of Magento should i go?.
If I develop the magento for version 2.0 , it should support for older version 1.x. or else 1.x extension supports 2.0.?

Comment: you should develop two separate versions of your extension one for 1x series and another one for 2X series. As both  versions have different way the module is created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to develop for both version with different - different modules
but the best way 
you develop first for Magento 1.X version then according to that Convert that Module to 2.X version 
because in web you can find more Posts related to Version 1.x and build better logic according to your requirement .

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jayram.